# How to get this data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have something like this:

```
Time       EQID    STATUS  USER    
12:12am     EQ1     0       SA
12:14am     EQ1     1       SA
02:30am     EQ2     0       SA
03:30am     EQ2     1       SA
05:30am     EQ1     0       SA
06:30am     EQ2     1       SA
```

Now the required output is:

```
In_time   Out_time  EQID  USER
12:12am    12:14am   EQ1   SA
02:30am    03:30am   EQ2   SA
05:30am    06:30am   EQ1   SA
```

Here `In_time` is the time with status '0' and `Out_time` is the time with status '1'. How can I get this `In_time` and `Out_time` for that particular EQID and user.

Note: Like this I have so many rows with multiple users, how can I get this?

Comment: Please only capitalize the first word of a sentence, names of persons, and I. Don't randomly capitalize other words, it makes things harder to read.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Okay...

Comment: Shouldn't last record in example data be `EQ1`?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes it is  EQ1.I have to capture n times like the way mentioned in question

Comment: Which data type is the column "time" ?

Comment: @stb sorry? there is no column named type in question.please check once

Comment: "time", I just corrected :)

Comment: @stb actually it is datetime,but I mentioned in a way to understand clearly..data type is datetime

Comment: Can multiple 1 statuses happen in a row or will there always be a 0 inbetween when sorted by `Time`?

Comment: @EMUEVIL Yeah It has to be done with status. you have to consider status if it is 0 then capture the in_time and if 1 then out_time it will be tracked with eqid and user also. we have to take status, userid, eqid in consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #data (
    [Time] datetime,
    [EQID] nvarchar(10),
    [Status] bit,
    [User] nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #data VALUES ('2017-12-27 12:12am', 'EQ1', 0, 'SA')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES ('2017-12-27 12:14am', 'EQ1', 1, 'SA')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES ('2017-12-27 02:30am', 'EQ1', 0, 'SA')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES ('2017-12-27 03:30am', 'EQ1', 1, 'SA')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES ('2017-12-27 05:30am', 'EQ1', 0, 'SA')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES ('2017-12-27 06:30am', 'EQ1', 1, 'SA')

-- Get the next time where status is 1
SELECT D1.[Time] as 'In_Time'
    , D2.[Time] as 'Out_Time'
    , D1.[EQID]
    , D1.[User]
FROM #data D1
    LEFT JOIN #data D2
        ON D2.[Time] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Time]
                        FROM #data
                        WHERE [Status] = 1
                        AND [Time] > D1.[Time]
                        AND [User] = D1.[User]
                        AND [EQID] = D1.[EQID]
                        ORDER BY [Time])
WHERE D1.[Status] = 0
```

Comment: Your join-condition query isn't sufficiently correlated.  It doesn't consider EQID or User.

Comment: @TabAlleman His example doesn't consider those fields either or else the out time for 'EQ1' wouldn't be 6:30am.  That value belongs to `EQ2` .  I guess it could be assumed that the user needs to be the same though...

Comment: Actually in the comments, OP stated that the last example row should actually be EQ1.   It has not been edited in the question as of yet, though.   But yes in the paragraph right after the desired output, OP states that EQID and User must both be considered.

Comment: Agree, this should work, it is one way of writing what I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman Oh! I didn't mean to step on your toes.  I'm just trying to write answers to practice my own ability and the OP wasn't clearly understanding what you were trying to teach (no fault of your own).  Sorry to spoil a learning experience!

Comment: Don't worry, my toes are fine.   : )

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do a main query of all the rows where Status=0.  That would give you all the columns except `out_time`.

Add to this, a correlated subquery to get `out_time` and get the first row (order by `Time`) where the EQID and User are the same as the main query, the status=1, and the `Time` is greater than the `Time` in the main query.

(In other words, the `out_Time` is the MIN `Time` for this EQID & User with Status=1 that is greater than the current Status=0 row.)

Comment: Didn't get you can you please write a sample query @TabAlleman

Comment: I have edited the answer for clarity.   I will not write the query for you, but if you make the attempt, I will help you debug it.

Comment: am getting subquery returns multiple value.. please help this one is driving me to nuts have been doing this since morning please help

Comment: Your subquery probably just needs a `TOP 1` in the SELECT list, but you would need to post the query for me to debug it.

Comment: @saibharath Your condition is probably matching multiple rows when you look for `Time` that is greater than the row you're looking at.  In my example answer, I used a `TOP 1` subquery to only return 1 result instead of all matching times that are after the In_time you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.

1. You are storing `TIME` as `VARCHAR`
2. You are storing the *TIME* without a `DATE` which makes it impossible to determine when a user clocked in on one day but didn't clock out on the next
3. You haven't alluded to what EQID is or why you chose EQ1 over EQ2 for the last row

With that being said... here is a way.

```
declare @table table (  [Time] varchar(64), 
                        EQID char(3), 
                        [STATUS] int, 
                        [USER] char(2))

insert into @table
values
('12:12am','EQ1',0,'SA'),
('12:14am','EQ1',1,'SA'),
('02:30am','EQ2',0,'SA'),
('03:30am','EQ2',1,'SA'),
('05:30am','EQ1',0,'SA'),
('06:30am','EQ2',1,'SA')

;with cte as(
select
    [Time]
    ,EQID
    ,[USER]
    ,[Status]
    ,RN = row_number() over(partition by [USER] order by cast(stuff([Time],6,0,' ') as time))
from 
    @table t)

select
    In_Time = i.[Time]
    ,Out_Time = o.[Time]
    ,i.EQID
    ,i.[USER]
from
    cte i
    left join cte o on
    o.[USER] = i.[USER]
    and o.RN = i.RN + 1
where
    i.[STATUS] = 0
```